# boost::any destructor crash

Tags: c++, boost, dll, destructor, boost-any

Main exe loads dll. Calls function from dll returning simple boost::any. If boost::any deleted after FreeLibrary app crash at destructor. It's ok. But I can't understand why this code also crash at r2 destructor, r2 created in main and delete doesn't need dll code.
How can I save boost::any after FreeLibrary.
Tried without extern "C" - same effect.

Console code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  any r2;

  HMODULE hmod = LoadLibrary(L"dll");
  typedef any (*dllfunc)(int,int,int);
  dllfunc func = (dllfunc) GetProcAddress(hmod,"Export1");

  { 
    any r = func(1,2,3);
    r2 = r;
  }

  FreeLibrary(hmod);
  return 0;
}
```

Dll code:

```
extern "C" 
{
  DLL_API any Export1(int a,int b, int c)
  {
    return a+b+c;
  }
}
```

compiler Visual Studio 2005

Comment: Are you sure the calling conventions match? I would never pass anything more complex than a pointer through dynamically loaded functions...

Comment: I'm with PlasmaHH. Dynamically linking doesn't mesh well with C++ ABI, template code, exceptions etc.

Comment: Found an answer, but not solution. When you copy boost::any it calls virtual method clone() which executes inside dll so virtual table of the new object resides in dll also.

Comment: To save boost::any you need to extract content. Only serialize can help, but there is no such function.

Comment: This is just how DLLs work. All objects that come from a DLL need to be destroyed before that DLL is unloaded -- including the instance of `any` returned by Export1. (This is one of the reasons that C++ APIs across DLLs are strongly not recommended)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what actually `any` is. For instance it might be a `shared_ptr` to some object with destructor, whereas the destructor code resides in the DLL. Then all the instances of `any` should be destroyed prior to DLL unload.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a memory manager not handling null pointers.